# fetch from two json files data ajax node

Tags: node.js, ajax

The JSON files src1 and src2 contain a list of video items.  I created a web page that will initially load data via AJAX from src1.json and src2.json.  The only difference is that src2.json has rating field; how can i combine them to make only one call in ajax to present in an htmlfile?  Is it possible to be done with node.js and ajax?

src1.json

```
[
    {
        'id' : 67544,
        'title' : 'Title 7',
        'posttime' : '2017-03-21T10:56:11.404Z',
        'tags' : [
            'green',
            'red',
            'blue'
        ]
    },
    {
        'id' : 333,
        'title' : 'Title 9',
        'posttime' : '2017-01-01T09:01:10.404Z',
        'tags' : [
            'orange',
            'purple'
        ]
    },
    {
        'id' : 444,
        'title' : 'Title 8',
        'posttime' : '2017-03-02T07:12:00.404Z',
        'tags' : [
            'magenta',
            'red',
            'yellow'
        ]
    }
]
```

src2.json

```
[
    {
        'id' : 43423,
        'title' : ' Title 1',
        'posttime' : '2017-03-21T10:56:42.404Z',
        'rating' : 1000,
        'tags' : [
            'green',
            'red',
            'blue'
        ]
    },
    {
        'id' : 342334,
        'title' : 'Title 2',
        'posttime' : '2017-03-21T09:56:42.404Z',
        'rating' : 100,
        'tags' : [
            'orange',
            'purple'
        ]
    },
    {
        'id' : 66343,
        'title' : 'Title 3',
        'posttime' : '2017-03-21T10:52:42.404Z',
        'rating' : 30,
        'tags' : [
            'magenta',
            'red',
            'yellow'
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "src1.json";
  var url2 = "src1.json";

    enter code here

  $("button").click(function() {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      $('#mydiv').append((JSON.stringify(data)));
    });
    $.get(url2, function(data) {
      $('#mydiv').append((JSON.stringify(data)));
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community. What have you tried so far? The purpose of SO is not for other people to write the program for you, but we will happily help you if can provide more _specific_ problems (for example: "I tried this approach but it doesn't work since only half the items are included" is a good problem description.)

Please see this web page for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: updated check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you are aiming for is something like:

1. Load `src1.json`, and parse it.
2. Load `src2.json`, and parse it.
3. Combine the arrays produced to a new array.

So if the question is: *can you make an HTTP backend in node.js that does this*? The answer to that question is clearly: yes, it can be done. Take a look at e.g. Expressjs: https://expressjs.com/, it's a framework for easily creating HTTP web applications with node.js.

Actually concatenating the arrays in Javascript should be simple, once you have read the files into memory and parsed them. Something like this should do:

```
$ node
> a = [1,2,3]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
> b = [4,5,6]
[ 4, 5, 6 ]
> a.concat(b)
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```